# Change header for `memoir` class

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, memoir

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Prolog}
\lipsum
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter at the Beginning}
\lipsum
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum
\chapter{Three}
\lipsum
\chapter{Four}
\lipsum
\chapter{Five}
\lipsum
\chapter{Six}
\lipsum
\chapter{Seven}
\lipsum
\chapter{Eight}
\lipsum
\chapter{Nine}
\lipsum
\chapter{Ten}
\lipsum
\chapter{Eleven}
\lipsum
\chapter{Twelve}
\lipsum
\chapter{Thirteen}
\lipsum
\chapter{Fourteen}
\lipsum
\chapter{Fifteen}
\lipsum
\chapter{Sixteen}
\lipsum
\chapter{Seventeen}
\lipsum
\chapter{Nineteen}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

How to make chapter header (including ToC) not all upper case? For example for chapter one I want the header to be *1. Chapter at the Beginning* and not *1. CHAPTER AT THE BEGINNING*, for ToC I want it to be *Contents* not *CONTENTS*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (section **7.2 PAGE STYLES**):

```
\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{headings}
```

Comment: This could be a template for answers :)

Comment: @DrManuelKuehner one could also link to my practex journal article about memoir pagestyles. Might be easier to understand than the manual (note to self, I should do something about that)

Comment: I would also like to get the link. Never used memoir before.

Comment: http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/, dang that 10 years ago...