# Too much information scattered widely

Tags: documentation

Many questions on texSE have previously documented answers ([for instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429901/change-header-for-memoir-class)).
The answers may be in published books (e.g *The LaTeX Companion*), the many user manuals, *TUGboat*, *The PracTeX Journal*, somewhat old but *TeX and TUG News* and I understand that there are various sources (of doubtful quality) of *Wiki*like documents.

Is there anyone foolhardy enough to try and make sense out of the chaos? I'm thinking along the lines of an index-like thing that given a problem will point to document(s) providing possible solutions (but perhaps one of the *Wiki* things already does that.

GOM

Comment: The search facilities here are not too bad, particularly if you sort by votes.  OTOH, many questions deal with obscure packages, bad templates and oddball formatting requests.

Comment: Since the dawn of times people have been reasking questions for which answers existed and could be easily found e.g. two threads below, on the first page of a documentation or as one of the first hits of some search machine. People who search find such things through the existing means, people who don't search don't. No new search method will  imho change this.

Comment: Is this more of a meta.tex question?

Comment: The [TeX User Group](http://tug.org/) website is a good starting point. From the home page you can find links to [Getting started](http://tug.org/begin.html), the [FAQ](http://faq.tug.org/) and [TeX around the Web](http://tug.org/interest.html).

Comment: It is just entropy growing.  Nothing to do here.  People will continue to create new material.  It is easier than sorting out the existing stuff.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  Thanks for editing the URL in my question to get a link. Reading the editing-help page it seemed to me that `<url>` should have printed `url` but it didn't. What did you do to get the `for instance` link to the `url`?

Comment: @PeterWilson The markup in this site allows for basic HTML so you could have, for instance, used 
`<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>` to find out how to do it (not telling you to Google it, just an example :). Other than that, the markup language of StackExchange allows you to use `[Google](www.google.com)` or also `[Google][1]` provided that later you have `[1]: www.google.com.br`. Of course, there is always the  button as a shortcut :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking back I think that this was not a sensible question. If I ever tried I would fail at producing something like I was asking for even just limited to the classes/packages I have created over the years, never mind the span of all the *TeX systems.

If anyone wants to delete the question then go ahead. On the other hand I found that the comments were very useful to me.
Following @NicolaTalbot suggestion here is a summary of the comments I found useful.

@JohnKormylo said that the search facilities are not too bad particularly if sorted by votes.

@UlrikeFischer said that people who search will find things but those that don't, don't. New search methods will not change this.

@NicolaTalbot the [TeX User Group website](https://tug.org) is a good starting point. From the home page you can find links to [Getting started](https://tug.org/begin.html), the [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq/) and [TeX around the Web](https://tug.org/interest.html). With undue modesty she forgot to mention her series of [Dickimaw TeX books](https://www.dickimaw-books/people/nicola-talbot.html)

Comment: Since comments are transient, it might be worth summarising them in your answer. It could make a useful reference.